# Spring - Connections not released

Tags: java, spring

Im doing insert to Oracle database, two schemas and two tables, I have created two XA datasources in Jboss 6.3.2, with same URL but different users,
For each call I create new transaction, and what happens is after some time I get error that no connection is available. I guess that connections are not released. Im not experienced in spring so I will need an advice if my implementation is wrong.

exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/jdbc/tivibu_stb
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
```

Interface:

```
@RequestMapping  
@Transactional  
public interface RRStatisticsService {  

@Cache(CacheType.NO_CACHE)  
@AuthRequired(AuthType.USER)  
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)  
@RequestMapping(value = "/private/rr/sendChannelEvents.ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public @ResponseBody void sendChannelEvents(@Valid @RequestBody ChannelRatingEvents events,  
        @SubscriberId String subscriberId, @UserId String userId, @DeviceId String deviceId) throws PortalException;  

@Cache(CacheType.NO_CACHE)  
@AuthRequired(AuthType.USER)  
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)  
@RequestMapping(value = "/private/rr/sendVodEvents.ajax", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public @ResponseBody void sendVodEvents(@Valid @RequestBody VodRatingEvents events,  
        @SubscriberId String subscriberId, @UserId String userId, @DeviceId String deviceId) throws PortalException;  
}
```

Bean:

```
@Controller  
public class RRBean implements RRStatisticsService {  

@Override  
public void sendChannelEvents(ChannelRatingEvents events, String subscriberId, String userId, String deviceId)  
        throws PortalException {  
    saveChannelRatingEvents(events, subscriberId, userId, deviceId);  
}  



@Override  
public void sendVodEvents(VodRatingEvents events, String subscriberId, String userId, String deviceId)  
        throws PortalException {  
    saveVodRatingEvents(events, subscriberId, userId, deviceId);  
}  


private void saveChannelRatingEvents(ChannelRatingEvents events, String subscriberId, String userId,  
    String deviceId) throws SomeException {    
    try {      
        JdbcTemplate template = getJdbcTemplate(userId, deviceId, events.getClientType());           
        insertChannelRating(events, subscriberId, userId, template);  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
       //Handle exception  
    }  
}  


private void insertChannelRating(ChannelRatingEvents events, String subscriberId, String userId, JdbcTemplate template){      
      template.batchUpdate(SQL_CHANNEL_RATING, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {  
          @Override  
          public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {  
              ChannelRatingEvent event = rrevents.get(i);  
              ps.setString(1, event.getChannelViewID());  
              ps.setString(2, event.getChannelName());  
              ps.setInt(3, event.getChannelID());  
              ps.setInt(4, event.getStreamFlag());  
              ps.setInt(5, events.getClientType());  
              ps.setDate(6, event.Date());  
              ps.setString(7, userId);  
              ps.setString(8, subscriberId);  
              ps.setString(9, "0");  
              ps.setDate(10, event.Date());  
          }  
          @Override  
          public int getBatchSize() {  
              return rrevents.size();  
          }  
      });  
}  

private void saveVodRatingEvents(VodRatingEvents events, String subscriberId, String userId, String deviceId)  
        throws SomeException {  
    try {  
        JdbcTemplate template = getJdbcTemplate(userId, deviceId, events.getClientType());  
        insertVodRating(events, subscriberId, userId, template);  
    } catch (Exception e) {  
 //HANDLE EXCEPTION  
    }  
}  



private void insertVodRating(VodRatingEvents events, String subscriberId, String userId, JdbcTemplate template){  

    template.batchUpdate(SQL_VOD_RATING, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {  
        @Override  
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {  
            VodRatingEvent event = rrevents.get(i);  
            ps.setString(1, event.getVodViewID());  
            ps.setString(2, event.getVodName());  
            ps.setString(3, event.getAssetID());  
            ps.setInt(4, event.getVodType());  
            ps.setInt(5, event.getVodSegment());  
            ps.setInt(6, clientType);  
            ps.setDate(7, event.getDate());  
            ps.setString(8, userId);  
            ps.setString(9, subscriberId);  
            ps.setString(10, "0");  
            ps.setDate(11, event.getDate());  
        }  
        @Override  
        public int getBatchSize() {  
            return rrevents.size();  
        }       
    });  
}  

private JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(String userId, String deviceId, Integer clientType) {         
DataSource dataSource = null;  
    JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();        
    String dataSourceJndi;  
    if (clientType.intValue() == 0) {  
    dataSourceJndi = getUserPreferences(userId, deviceId).get(STB_DS_PREF_KEY);   
        }  
    } else {  
    dataSourceJndi = getUserPreferences(userId, deviceId).get(OTT_DS_PREF_KEY);   
        }  
    }  

    try {  
        dataSource = (DataSource) jndi.lookup(dataSourceJndi);  
    } catch (NamingException e) {  
        logger.error("NamingException for " + dataSourceJndi, e);  
        return null;  
    }  

    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);  
}  
}
```

stbportal-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Component auto-scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ericsson.iptv.portal.avalanche.tt.rr.iap" />
```

Datasource definition:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/tivibu_stb" pool-name="jdbc_tivibu_stb" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">  
                    <xa-datasource-property name="User">  
                        USER2  
                    </xa-datasource-property>  
                    <xa-datasource-property name="Password">  
                        PWD2  
                    </xa-datasource-property>  
                    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">  
                        jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostip2:1521:TTEST2  
                    </xa-datasource-property>  
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>  
                    <driver>ojdbc</driver>  
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>  
                    <xa-pool>  
                        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>  
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>  
                        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>  
                        <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>  
                        <interleaving>false</interleaving>  
                        <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>  
                        <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>  
                        <wrap-xa-resource>false</wrap-xa-resource>  
                    </xa-pool>  
                    <validation>  
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>  
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>  
                    </validation>  
                    <timeout>  
                        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>  
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>  
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>  
                        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>  
                        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>  
                        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>  
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>  
                        <xa-resource-timeout>0</xa-resource-timeout>  
                    </timeout>  
                    <statement>  
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>  
                    </statement>  
                </xa-datasource>
```

Comment: Are you closing the ApplicationContent after your code (business logic) finishes running.

Comment: ((FileSystemXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
  
  ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ) context).close();   ----> Which ever applies .

Comment: @KalyanChavali why on earth do you want him to close the context... That will basically destroy the application. You should never have to close it nor have to construct it yourself (only once during startup). I see a `@Transactional` but nowhere `<tx:annotation-driven />` without that the `@Transactional` is pretty much doing nothing. Also you should not create a `JdbcTemplate` each time you need it, create it once and reuse. Do the jndi lookup in the application context and construct a `JdbcTemplate` there and simply inject it.

Comment: I created jdbc template this way because i have jndi lookup name stored in application properties. I will try what you suggested. Thanks!